# Can not hide StatusBar in Windows Media Player 10 embedded to webpage

Tags: javascript, html, windows-media-player, wmp

I cant get this to work. Strangely, the `<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">` has no impact at all. Also, there is no "showStatusBar" property in my wmp object (JavaScript).

```
var obj = '<object id="_wmp" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" TYPE="application/x-oleobject" width="' + parseInt(parsed.width) + '" height="' + (parseInt(parsed.height) + 0) + '" codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/">';
obj += '<param name="URL" value="' + parsed.path + '">';
obj += '<param name="wode" value="transparent">';
obj += '<param name="windowlessVideo" value="true">';
obj += '<param name="autostart" value="true">';
obj += '<param name="ShowControls" value="true">';
obj += '<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">'; // does not work
obj += '<param name="showtracker" value="0">'; // has no effect
obj += '<param name="showstatusbar" value="0">'; // has no effect
obj += '</object>';
```

The obj then gets inserted to the document, I can control it in the console (for instance with `_wmp.controls.stop()` ) but I cant seem to hide the statusbar?

The reason why I want to hide it is because of the status bar the playlist and clip info is being shown, which generates an unwanted additional frame around the video. Also, when re-inserting the video, there is always a playlist info like "playlist 12", "playlist 13" and so on.

For other wmp versions, I am also appending an object with `CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95` which works perfectly fine hiding the statusbar. Ideas on this?

How can I completely remove the status bar and/or change/remove the playlist info with html and javascript?

Thanks!